# Access items and attributes across multiple windows

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

i have a main GUI-Window from which i open a new Window (FCT-popup) with a buttonclick:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # sets ui = to the main window from the ui-file
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        [...]
    def enter_fct_results(self):
        self.FCTpopup = FCT_Window()
        self.FCTpopup.show()
```

In the Window i have a QTable to fill and a button to submit the data and close the window:

```
    class FCT_Window(QMainWindow):
    
     def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_FCT_Window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        [...]

        self.ui.pushButton_submitFCT.clicked.connect(lambda: MainWindow.store_fct_data(MainWindow, self.on_submit()[0]))

     def on_submit(self):  # event when user clicks
                  fct_nparray = np.zeros((self.ui.tableFCTinputs.rowCount(), self.ui.tableFCTinputs.columnCount()))
                      for j in range(self.ui.tableFCTinputs.columnCount()):
                            for i in range(self.ui.tableFCTinputs.rowCount()):
                                fct_nparray[i, j] = float(self.ui.tableFCTinputs.item(i, j).text())
                  return  fct_nparray, lambda: self.close()
    
    self.ui.pushButton_submitFCT.clicked.connect(lambda: MainWindow.store_fct_data(MainWindow, self.on_submit()[0]))
```

The receiving function iin the main window looks like ths:

```
def store_fct_data(self, data):
    self.fct_data = data
```

Now i just want to understand how i can make either the mainwindow or the pushbutton which opens the 2nd window disabled. Disabling inside enter_fct_results() works, but if i want to enable it again with either store_fct_data or on_submit provides errors like this:

```
self.ui.pushButton_FCTresults.setEnabled(1)
self.ui.pushButton_submitFCT.clicked.connect(lambda: MainWindow.store_fct_data(MainWindow, self.on_submit()[0]))
AttributeError: type object 'MainWindow' has no attribute 'ui'
```

I dont think i have understood it here how to deal with multiple windows and stuff. For example how would i change a the color of a button in the main window by using a button in window2. How do i access the widgets? if i am inside the same Window i do that easily by

```
self.ui.pushbutton.setText("New Text")
```

I dont get how to access items and attributes across Windows  :( Can you help me?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Access to attributes of another *instance*

There is a fundamental difference between disabling the button of the second window in `enter_fct_results` and what you tried in the lambda: in the first case, you're accessing an *instance* attribute (for instance, `self.FCTpopup.ui.pushButton`), while in the second you're trying to access a *class* attribute.

The `self.ui` object is created in the `__init__` (when the class instance is created), so the *instance* will have an `ui` attribute, **not** the class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = True

test = Test()
print(test.value)

>>> True

print(Test.value)

>>> AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'value'
```

### Provide a *reference*

The simple solution is to create a reference of the instance of the first window *for* the second:

```
   def enter_fct_results(self):
        self.FCTpopup = FCT_Window(self)
        self.FCTpopup.show()

class FCT_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow
        self.ui.pushButton_submitFCT.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)

    def doSomething(self):
        # ...
        self.mainWindow.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
```

### Using *modal windows* (aka, dialogs)

Whenever a window is required for some temporary interaction (data input, document preview, etc), a dialog is preferred: the main benefit of using dialogs is that they are *modal* to the parent, preventing interaction on that parent until the dialog is closed; another benefit is that (at least on Qt) they also have a *blocking* event loop within their [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) function, which will only return as soon as the dialog is closed. Both of these aspects also make unnecessary disabling any button in the parent window. Another important reason is that QMainWindow is not intended for this kind of operation, also because it has features that generally unnecessary for that (toolbars, statusbars, menus, etc).

```
   def enter_fct_results(self):
        self.FCTpopup = FCT_Window(self)
        self.FCTpopup.exec_()

class FCT_Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui.pushButton_submitFCT.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)

    def doSomething(self):
        # ...
        self.accept()
```

The above makes *mandatory* to recreate the ui in designer using a QDialog (and not a QMainWindow) instead. You can just create a new one and drag&drop widgets from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found my mistake: It was the place of the signal connection. It has to be right before the 2nd window is opened:

```
def enter_fct_results(self):
    self.FCTpopup = Dialog(self.fct_data)
    self.FCTpopup.submitted.connect(self.store_fct_data)
    self.FCTpopup.exec_()
```

With this now i can send the stored data from the mainwindow to the opened window, import into the table, edit it and send it back to the main window on submit.